# How to load nested key value pairs from a properties file in SpringBoot

Tags: java, spring, apache, spring-boot

Is there a better manner to implement properties file having key-value pairs as value using Spring/Spring Boot?
I want to create a property file where the key contains a couple of key-value pair as value.

I tried below implementation:-

Properties file:-

```
Fiat=model:pet,year:1996
Honda=model:dis,year:2000
```

And i have below class trying to read the properties file.

```
@Component
@PropertySources(@PropertySource("classpath:sample.properties"))
public class PropertiesExtractor {

    @Autowired
    private Environment env;

    public String pullValue(String node) {

    String value = env.getProperty(node);
    System.out.println(value);//for Fiat, i get syso as **model:pet,year:1996**
}
```

}

I need to parse the values using java, to get the individual value. Is this the only way out to implement this.

Is there a better way to use nested property files in Java?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use yaml files with spring as well:

http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/boot-features-external-config.html#boot-features-external-config-yaml

This way, you can work with

```
Fiat:
  model: pet
  year: 1996
Honda:
  model: dis
  year: 2000
```

Answer (score 5):

Create a `Car` object or something with a `model` and a `year` property. Then create something like this

```
@ConfigurationProperties("foo")
public class CarProperties {

    private Map<String,Car> cars;

    // Getters/Setters
}
```

Add add `@EnableConfigurationProperties(CarProperties.class)` in your main configuration class.

Then you can inject that config as follows:

```
foo.cars.Fiat.model=pet
foo.cars.Fiat.year=1996
foo.cars.Honda.model=dis
foo.cars.Honda.year=2000
```

There is more info in the doc.